# Multiple column names for $title in Laravel Nova select

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Is it possible to group several column names and use them as the label / title in a select BelongsTo, I don't want to use ID and don't have a 'name' field as such as the table in question is like this:

- Country
- State
- Cost

So the dropdown should be able to allow the user to see those names like:

---

USA | Washington | $50.00

USA | California | $80.00

USA | Texas | $30.00

---

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Documentation says](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/relationships.html#title-attributes), that you may override the resource's title method:

```
/**
 * Get the value that should be displayed to represent the resource.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function title()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

For some form specific display you can use:

```
BelongsTo::make('SomeModel', 'somemodel', 'App\Nova\SomeModel')
         ->display(function($someModel){ 
             return $someModel->id.' wow so custom, much id'; 
         }),
```

Comment: I only want to override the title in the field on the form screen. The doc you cited is for the resource itself from what I gathered

Comment: Awesome - thanks a lot! Do you know if in the index view it's possible to then make this 'display' as a 'show more' expand

Comment: @user1983183 index display can be changed with ->displayUsing(), but not sure that html/link allowed inside.

Comment: No worries - I'll build a second field for index view and one for forms only. Thanks again